# how to convert Arraylist<myClass> in JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I'm trying to convert Generic `ArrayList` in `JSONArray` but it is displaying **null** value.

but this is working fine if i'm trying to display specific value from `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<myClass> experience = new ArrayList<>();

... //adding some values


 Log.v("testing", experience.get(0).company);  //this is showing value

        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(experience);

        Log.v("testing", json.toString()); //this is showing [null]
```

Comment: Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem recognizing andn converting your "myClass" bean to json. 
Try using  **gson library** to create json and to parse it back to object .

Answer (score 0):

Replace with Below Code and try it will work.

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
 String json = gson.toJson(experience);
 Log.e("Jason Array", json);
```

Comment: its showing fully qualified name like
`com.example.project.SeekerProfile@425025f0`

Answer (score 0):

Can use GSON library like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonArray myCustomArray = gson.toJsonTree(myCustomList).getAsJsonArray();
```